# Display a rotated image upright

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have a left-oriented image named "test.png" (like the 'R' image annotation of the doc of UIImageOrientationLeft), I first read it in with UIImage, and then create another UIImage with the image data of the first one and the orientation info, like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test"];
image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:1.f orientation:UIImageOrientationLeft];
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
[imageView sizeToFit];
```

But the image displayed on imageView is upside-down. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it is a bit confusing. `UIImageOrientationLeft` corresponds to EXIF Orientation Tag 6 not 8. "Left" in `UIImageOrientationLeft` means the image *needs to be rotated left* to display properly, not the image *is* rotated left. So a left-oriented image loaded in a `UIImage` with  `UIImageOrientationLeft` will be rotated left once more when displaying, resulting in an upside-down image.

Comment: Correct, there's a good generic explanation of this photo behavior here: http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/digitalphotography/f/sideways-pictures.htm

Answer (score 1):

I spent a great deal of time on this topic over the last few weeks.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307521/ios-png-image-rotated-90-degrees) might help you, but for a more in depth explanation, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600613/ios-image-orientation-has-strange-behavior) out.

Between the two posts, there is information for why the images are rotated, as well as how to rotate them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

That's because UIImage is supposed to automatically handle orientations and in this case, it was flipped twice. Note: one shouldn't rely on data provided by various image handling objects when it comes to RAW images.

Comment: So the problem is that the CGImage data read from UIImage may not be what I expect? If I read raw data into CGImage myself, then I can still use imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation: to create UIImage as I want, right?

Comment: You can use combinations of methods to load images in whatever way you like but be prepared for some problems with RAW images because since the last time I checked, there were still bugs with getting correct orientation for example: Nikon RAW photos.